# How to the set orientation for spin tool

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling an m26 grenade, specifically the top part (pic 1).  Ive used the spin tool to extrude and move down the top part of the clip (pic 2) . I want to do the same to the bottom face (pic 3) by using the spin tool and match the way the curve moves inward, however I cant seem to replicate the top spin and am struggling to find the correct orientation for it without causing weird spins to occur... any help?

[image]

[image]

I've created the curve going down (A) but want to do the same for the other side (B) on a different angle

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the face you want to spin, then use View >> Align View >> Align View to Active. Find the view you need to see along your desired spin axis and spin. You can use a second window to do the selection if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to modeling this handle similar to how it was probably manufactured "Stamped":

Start with a flat version spine the two prongs in the front. Add three Loop Cuts where the edges of the side pieces are. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image: Loop Cuts]

In the tail end of the mesh add a bunch of Loop Cuts. I used 30.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> Mouse wheel to 30.

[image: 30 Loop Cuts]

Select the following Edges and place the Cursor approximately here and use the Spin Tool <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> You can adjust the angle and increments in the Tool Panel (Pressing <kbd>T</kbd> toggles the panel on/off).

[image: Spin]

Extrude those same edges down a bit <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Extrude Down]

Select the following Edge and Extrude down some more <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Extrude]

Select the following Edges and Extrude  theem down <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: Extrude]

Hide everything but the following.

[image: Hide]

Enable Proportional Editing with a Linear Falloff and scale the bottom Edge inward <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

[image: Proportional Scale]

Select the bottom middle Vertex and change the Falloff to Sphere to create the following shape.

[image: Sphere]

Select the back edge and change the Falloff to Sharp and drag down to create this shape <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>SHFT</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> To constrain the movement to the x and z axis.

[image]

Disable Proportional Editing. Change the Pivot Center to the 3D Cursor. Select all of the following and Rotate on the Y axis <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd>

[image: Rotate]

[image: Final]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough guide Dontwalk and for taking the time to do it!